# EnterTransition working while exitTransition() not working

Tags: android, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

Trying to put enter & exit transition to an activity which is opening a fragment. Following are the steps followed.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);

        TransitionSet enterTransitionSet = new TransitionSet();
        enterTransitionSet.addTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move));
        enterTransitionSet.setDuration(400);
        enterTransitionSet.setStartDelay(0);
        getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(enterTransitionSet);

        Slide enterSlide = new Slide();
        enterSlide.setStartDelay(300);
        enterSlide.setDuration(300);
        getActivity().getWindow().setEnterTransition(enterSlide);

        Fade exitFade = new Fade();
        exitFade.setStartDelay(300);
        exitFade.setDuration(300);
        getActivity().getWindow().setExitTransition(exitFade);

    }
}
```

Issue : Enter transition is successfully applied as slide, while the exit transition for window is not reflecting. Activity is exiting with slide effect only without any delay or so.

Comment: Sorry, didnt copy from the code. Now corrected here. 
Issue persists, not able to set fade transition while exiting from the activity.